# How to get the number of values in an array in .Net?

Tags: axapta, business-connector

AX allows arrays to be defined, but while fetching information through the .NET Business Connector, it shows as a single field. E.g: Dimension is set by:

```
axRec.setField("Dimension[1]","A");
axRec.setField("Dimension[2]","B");
axRec.setField("Dimension[3]","C");
// and so on...
```

How do I know how many fields "Dimension" have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AX supports a compile time function `dimOf` to return the count, but that is not available from .Net!

To rescue comes the `DictField` class:

X++ code:

```
DictField df = new DictField(tablenum(CustTable), fieldnum(CustTable, AccountNum));   
if (df)  
{ 
    print strfmt("The arraySize is %1.", df.arraySize());  
}
```

You can make a X++ utility function, then call that:

```
static int arraySize(str tableName, str fieldName)
{
    DictField df = new DictField(tableName2Id(tableName), fieldName2Id(tableName2Id(tableName), fieldName)));   
    return df ? df.arraySize() : -1;  
}
```